# Creating an Interactive Multi Field Search Bar in MS-ACCESS

Tags: ms-access, filter, field, interactive, records

I know this is probably a simple thing I'm missing, but I'm hoping you all can help. I'm trying to add a textbox to my form that allows users to type in search criteria and have the query filter the records to only display those that qualify. The trick is I want the user to be able to type in info and have it check all the fields of the form and return records for any that are valid.

I set up a query with the fields that I want checked and I watched a few tutorials on setting criteria, but they are all working with multiple search bars. Is there a way to do it with only 1?

```
Like "*" Or [Forms]![Publications Page]![FilterBox] OR "*"
```

This is the criteria expression I wrote. It returns records just not the ones I want and doesn't seem to change after I change what is in [FilterBox]. I have 4 fields I'm running this same criteria on. All thoughts and suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Put an `&` in place of each `Or`. Put that criteria expression under each field you want to apply to.

Answer (score 0):

The resulting criteria should be something like

```
[LastName] Like '*searchtext*' Or [FirstName] Like '*searchtext*' Or ...
```

So, you would have to set up a single criteria like this

```
Dim crit As String

crit = " Like '*" & Replace(Me!FilterBox, "'", "''") & "*' "
```

where the replace statement replces single (') by 2. This enables the user to enter an apostrophe in the search box.

Now you must create the whole criteria

```
crit = "[Field1]" & crit & "Or [Field2]" & crit & "Or [Field3]" & crit & "Or [Field4]" & crit
```

Comment: That looks to be like what I was trying to create thanks! Sorry for another newb question, but where would I put that criteria code in this case? Can I do a dim in the criteria tab of a query? Oh and I won't need apostrophes at any point so I'm hoping that simplifies things a bit.

Comment: I assumed this was VBA code inside a Form and you would put this code in the AfterUpdate event Sub  of a filter text box. In a filter tab, you would have to enter `Like "*" & [Forms]![Publications Page]![FilterBox] & "*"` in every filter field.

Comment: Awesome! It's working. There is only one other thing that seems to be awry. If I type in total gibberish into the filterbox it is returning a random record. Any thoughts?

Comment: I found that is works for finding records that are there, but only if I add that criteria code to both the AfterUpdate and the _Exit subs. If I remove it from one or the other it starts giving me random records.

Comment: I also noticed that if I add the code you wrote for a filter tab it has issues. I think that is because I'm only writing my search in one textbox while it is trying to find that answer in each of the fields. That was why I was thinking it was OR and not AND. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Correction. I didn't realize that you had to put them on new lines for each tab. Now it is working perfectly. Thank you!